# How to disassociate my email that I am not using anymore

Tags: support, status-completed

I was told to post a meta question to disassociate my email that I am not using anymore. I have associated a new email to this account, and would like my old email of gmail to be removed from this account.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily take care of this yourself. See [the instructions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-an-openid-or-login):

> 1. Open your profile page
> 2. Click the "my logins" link near the top
> 3. Click the little (x) to the right of the login you wish to remove.

Comment: Thanks. I successfully done it.